# How to detect when the desktop 'Progman' is on foreground?

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

There's any window event that happens or any WINAPI, in could tell me when the desktop becomes the `foreground window`?

So far what I tried was listening to `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART` using `SetWinEventHook` and on each notification compare the title/class to check if it's 'Progman'.

I wonder if there's any 'better' option to do this.

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that? If you want to do that, call GetDesktopWindow() and compare it with GetForegroundWindow() on a timer.

Comment: @mic Why a timer? The OP already subscribed to WinEvents, so that's where you can do the check. No need to waste CPU cycles, prevent the system from entering power saving state, and no opportunity to miss a transient state because it happened inside your arbitrarily chosen sampling interval.

Comment: @IInspectable OK. Perhaps the hook costs more than a timer but I wonder what exactly he is trying to achieve.

Comment: I could compare the `HWND` returned by the `SetWinEventHook` with the ´HWND` returned by `GetDesktopWindow()`? also, this `HWND`(GetDesktopWindow()) remains the same until a reboot?

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just need to know when the desktop become the foreground...

Comment: The value returned by `GetDesktopWindow()` remains the same value until it is destroyed. It gets destroyed on reboot, for example. It may also get destroyed when restarting the Shell (I'm not sure about this, though).

Comment: *"I just need to know when the desktop become the foreground..."* - Sure, we understood the literal question that is being asked. The thing that's unclear is what you are planning to do with that information. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? This certainly sounds like an instance of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I would guess the desktop window belongs to csrss and it goes away when the user logs out. It is the only HWND guaranteed to exist in a session.